# AppDelegate should call the method if the screen orientation has changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, screen-rotation

I have a `popover`, which I present from the `TabBarItem` thats why I make it in `AppDelegate`, but I need to reshow `popover` in new place if the screen orientation has changed. In other places of my app I just use the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method, but it doesn't called in `AppDelegate`. How can I solve this?

I present a popover by this code:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if (viewController == [self.objTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2])
        {
            if (self.settingsPopover == nil) {
                UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main - iPad" bundle: nil];
                SettingsViewController *settingsController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SettingsPopover"];

                UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];

                self.settingsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

                CGSize tabBarSize = self.objTabBarController.tabBar.frame.size;
                CGPoint center = [self.window.rootViewController.view convertPoint:self.objTabBarController.tabBar.center fromView:self.objTabBarController.tabBar.superview];
                center.x += 105;
                center.y -= tabBarSize.height / 2;
                CGRect rect = {center, CGSizeZero};

                [self.settingsPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.window.rootViewController.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
            } else {
                [self.settingsPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
                self.settingsPopover = nil;
            }

            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a `Notification` as follow:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Then, implement it in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)handleDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
  NSLog(@"The orientation changed to %@", [notification.userInfo objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey]);
}
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for prompt reply!